# CPU floating operations cost

Tags: performance, floating-point, cpu

I'm interesting in the time cost on a modern desktop CPU of some floating point operations in order to optimize a mathematical evaluation. In particular I'm interested on the comparison between complex operations like `exp`, `log` and simple operation like `+`, `*`, `/`.

I tried to search for this information, but I could't find a source.

What is the cost of floating point operations?

Comment: Why not just write a loop to do 10,000 `*` and 10,000 `exp` and collect the data?

Comment: What CPU? x86 family? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern CPUs will do float + and - in a few clocks.   Many will do * with a small number of clocks, but more than + and -.   Divide is usually considerably slower than *.   Transcendentals are slower than Divide.

You can likely get some ideas of speed by looking in Intel optimization manuals.

Comment: yes, this is what I need: page C-25 of the Intel optimization manual

Comment: Why I can find instruction for sin/cos/tan but not for log/exp?

Comment: They are there in the Intel instruction set.   I'm not sure it computes those directly; IIRC, it computes some intermediate result from which those can be computed quite easily.  Read over the FP instruction set carefully.

Comment: wiso, There are tables for many CPUs from Fog Agner: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf In Sandy Bridge, for example, compution of log (FYL2X) will take almost 500 microoperations (this instruction is microcoded) and 700+ clock ticks.

Comment: @wiso: Please be aware that good math libraries *do not* use the hardware transcendental operations for single or double precision, and instead use software implementations that are significantly *faster* than the instruction timings listed in the optimization manual (sometimes an order of magnitude faster).

Comment: @StephenCanon please elaborate further.